# Why is my Access report cutting off when printing?

Tags: ms-access, report

I have an Access report that has a couple subheaders, and when I run the report, I can see all of the data. However, if I go to print it or to export to PDF, it prints only the first and last pages. Interestingly, the page count that we have at the bottom will say pages 1 of 4 and 2 of 4 for those two pages that print/export, but it is clearly missing the data in the middle.

What it looks like is happening is that it prints the first section and all its subheaders, then (still on the first page) it prints as many of the subheaders in the second section as it can fit on the page and then can't fit any more on the page. Then it prints the last page and the data that would appear there.

How can I make sure that all the data that I see in the actual report actually appears in the printed/exported PDF version?

Comment: do you mean that the preview is different from the paper/pdf version ??

Comment: Check the page width, margins etc in the report. This used to cause me all sorts of issues when printing. I used to find that making the pages a bit narrower helps a lot.

Comment: @iDevlop: I mean that if I run the report, I can see all the data by scrolling down and looking at it. But the printed/PDF'd version only includes the first and last "page" of the document. The actual report itself is one document that you scroll down to see all the data on.

Comment: so, I ask again: the preview is different from the printed version ? (answer is yes or no)

Comment: I haven't looked at the "print preview" if that's what you mean. The report is called from another form and requires input to filter down to the data we want. Once the report is open/calculating I can't see a print preview. However, I suspect it would be the same as the physically printed report and the PDF. The report itself that appears on the screen (not the PDF) is fine, and all records can be seen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your view from "Report View" to "Print Preview".

"Report View" is **NOT** the same as "Print Preview"

Once you're in print preview you have the option of setting page size, margins, etc.